# sony vegas script: probleme to get directory path

Tags: c#, dll

I d like to create a blind test generator with a script using Sony vegas 14. For this I must make my script in C#.
I don’t have many experiences in C# so maybe my problem is a very basic one.

To do my script I must use a library class (.dll) and execute my script by Sony vegas. To test my code easily I create a console app where I try my code and can easily print in the console what my code does.
For my program y need to get the path of all subdirectory in a Directory in a string.

My problem is the next one.
the command "Directory.GetDirectories" don't work
When I use the next code to check what in my array/list I get a coherent result if I use it in the console app version on my script (the number of subdirectories in my directory)

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(myDirectorypath, "", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);// get all directory path in dirs


            Console.WriteLine("the number of element in your array is "+ dirs.Length);

            List<string> listdedossier = new List<string>(dirs); // convert the array in a list
            Console.WriteLine("the number of element in your list is " + listdedossier.Count);
```

But when in paste my code in my dll project nothing is written in my array or my list. I notice this because when I want to print the number of elements in the list /array that return me 0
.
do you have any idea of what happen i my code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check the online Microsoft documentation for [GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_). The 2nd argument is supposed to be a pattern to search for that conforms to Windows file name patterns. Essentially, all or part of a file name is allowed with `*` being a wildcard (The `.*` from regex meaning "match any character any number of times") and `?` being a single character wildcard (regex `.`). You are providing an empty string, so you get nothing back. The pattern `*.exe` will match all executables in a folder (if you are using `GetFiles`, while the pattern `pattern*` matches any files/folders that start with `pattern`. If you want all directories, do this:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(myDirectoryPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Next point, the path you provide can be either a relative path (e.g., "relative\path\to\folder"), an absolute path (e.g., "D:\path\to\folder"), or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN, e.g. "\servername.gov.edu.com\drive$\path\to\folder"). If you supply a relative path, you'll need to look up Windows' rules for path resolution. It is very easy using a relative path to search the wrong folder, or even a non-existent location (though you should get an exception in that case). Also remember: Windows path names are NOT case-sensitive.

Finally, when writing text with arguments, I HIGHLY recommend you use this format:

```
Console.WriteLine("The number of elements in your array is {0}", dirs.Length);
```

This uses a place holder in the string itself which has a numeric value in it. The number indicates what argument after the format string to use (0 is the first argument after the format string). You can use as many placeholders as you want, and use the same place holder in multiple locations. This is a more type-safe way to doing string printing in C# than using the `+` operator, which requires that an operator be defined that takes a string and whatever type you provided. When you use placeholders, `WriteLine` will use the built-in `ToString` method which is defined for all types in the `Object` class. Placeholders will *always* work, while using `+` will only sometimes work.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
i tried tu replace my `""` by `"*"` but it's change nothing, when i use my dll programme in sony vegas 'Directory.GetDirectories' give me always a empty array/string
by the way i am using an absolute path so in general this should not be a problem?

Comment: Print out the directory you are actually passing, and ensure it is a valid path for your OS (e.g., if Windows, ensure there is a leading drive letter). If the printed path is valid, check the directory itself to see if there is anything there. I just confirmed that any manner of ill-formatted path or non-existent path will result in an exception being thrown. So double check where you think you are reading from. If that isn't the problem, then there must be something in your environment that is causing an issue.